# Adiciono itens ao ArrayList mas quando vou utilizá-lo ele está vazio

Tags: android, arraylist

Não consigo adicionar itens ao meu ArrayList

Classe principal, onde o array é instanciado

```
public class act_principal extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private List<Medico> medicos = new ArrayList<Medico>();
```

Método onde os itens deveriam ser adicionados ao Array

```
public void setArrayMedico()
    {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, json_url_getMedicos, (String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                int codigo = 0;
                String nome="";

                for(int i=0; i<response.length(); i++)
                {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        codigo = jsonObject.getInt("Codigo");
                        nome = jsonObject.getString("Nome");

                        medicos.add(new Medico(codigo, nome));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequest(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
```

Quando debugo, ele insere normalmente no Array os itens, porém, quando acesso o Array após essa função, o mesmo está com size() == 0, ou seja, vazio. Onde está o meu erro?

Desde já, agradeço

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note que não é o método `setArrayMedico()` que preenche a lista mas sim o método `onResponse()`, da classe *JsonArrayRequest*.

Dito de outro modo: quando o método `setArrayMedico()` é chamado ele retorna de imediato, antes de a lista ser preenchida.

Se o código que está a utilizar é algo assim:

```
setArrayMedico();
boolean isEmpty = medicos.isEmpty();
```

`isEmpty` será `true`.

Uma solução possível será:

- Não declare o ArrayList como atributo da Activity, isso garantirá que não é usado sem estar preenchido.
- Declare um método que será chamado quando a lista estiver preenchida:

  ```
  private void onMedicosIsReady(List<Medico> medicos){

      //Utilize aqui a lista
  }
  ```
- No método `onResponse()` chame esse método depois da lista estar preenchida:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
      int codigo = 0;
      String nome="";

      //Declaração do ArrayList
      List<Medico> medicos = new ArrayList<Medico>();

      for(int i=0; i<response.length(); i++)
      {
          try {
              JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

              codigo = jsonObject.getInt("Codigo");
              nome = jsonObject.getString("Nome");

              medicos.add(new Medico(codigo, nome));

          } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
      //Chama o método quando estiver preenchido
      onMedicosIsReady(medicos);
  }
  ```

Comment: Certo, entendi. E como eu faria pra preencher meu ArrayList, se os dados que eu preciso estão no onResponse?

Comment: O problema é como(onde) está a utilizar o arraylist, pois ele é preenchido. Onde quer utilizar essa lista?

Comment: Sim, ele é preenchido, mas quando vou usar ele está vazio. O ideal seria chamar a setArrayMedico() para popular meu array, e na linha de baixo, jogar os dados para um ListView