# Retornar dados obtidos no OnResponse

Tags: java, android, volley

Como faço o retorno dessa String reponse?
Se eu dar o return ali ele não aceita... e se e por no fim do método e usar uma variável auxiliar corre o risco de retornar um null.

```
public String getData(){
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            Config.urlMaster,

            new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    JSONArray array;
                    try {
                        array = new JSONArray(response.toString());
                        String json = array.getJSONObject(0).toString();
                        Log.i("Script", "SUCCESS: "+response);

                        //return response; 
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(contexto, "Error: "+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){

    };

    request.setTag("tag");
    requisicao.add(request);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Relacionado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150458/2541

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O primeiro passo para resolver o problema é entender como funciona a execução do código.

Você está passando um objeto *listener* cujo método `onResponse` será invocado como um *callback* quando a requisição for finalizada. A execução de tal método não é linear, mas de natureza assíncrona.

Isso significa que o método principal vai acabar a execução e somente em algum momento depois o `onResponse` vai executar. Portanto, é impossível querer retornar o valor abaixo.

Existem duas formas de resolver isto. Uma delas é forçando o método principal a aguardar pela finalização da requisição. Porém esta é uma péssima prática, pois vai bloquear todo o programa. A maioria das APIs do Android são de natureza assíncrona justamente para evitar bloqueios e permitir cancelar tais operações.

Portanto, meu conselho seria que você mudasse sua estratégia. Ao invés de retornar os dados, você deve passar para o método um método *callback* que vai receber os dados e ser executado quando a requisição completar.

## Exemplo

Eu iria escrever um exemplo, mas encontrei algo que responde exatamente sua pergunta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120029/how-can-i-return-value-from-function-onresponse-of-volley). Vou apenas adaptar o código.

Primeiro você cria uma interface para servir de *callback*:

```
public interface VolleyCallback {
    void onSuccess(String response);
}
```

Depois altera seu método para receber o *callback*:

```
public void getData(final VolleyCallback callback) {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            Config.urlMaster,

            new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    JSONArray array;
                    try {
                        array = new JSONArray(response.toString());
                        String json = array.getJSONObject(0).toString();
                        Log.i("Script", "SUCCESS: "+response);

                        //passa o valor para o método callback
                        callback.onSuccess(response); 
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(contexto, "Error: "+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){

    };

    request.setTag("tag");
    requisicao.add(request);

    return null;
}
```

Finalmente, você chama o método passando o *callback* onde faz o que precisa fazer com os dados:

```
getData(new VolleyCallback() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(String response) {
         //executa a ação aqui com o response obtido
     }
});
```

Opcionalmente, você pode mostrar um *loader* para informar ao usuário que está carregando os dados e também implementar outro *callback* para tratar erros.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou como uma luva para mim... Só modifiquei algumas coisas para que para que ele me retornasse já um objeto enviado por parâmetro, desse modo eu aumentei a reusabilidade do meu método que pode ser usado para buscar qualquer dado do meu banco e transformá lo em qualquer modelo da minha aplicação, desde que passados os parâmetros corretamente. Não estou no PC, mas mais tarde postarei a solução desenvolvida